# PackageForTheWeb "should not be executed directly"

Tags: windows, drivers, installer, single-board

When trying to install package (specifically, chipset drivers for Nexcom PEAK-series computer, but I guess it doesn't really matters) I get "PackageForTheWeb Error" saing *"This program is used internally by PackageFromTheWeb. It should not be executed directly."* I get this error on both Windows 2000 (where it should be installed) and Windows 7.

The original driver CD was lost long time ago, so the package was downloaded from the Nexcom website, found no info about installer prerequisites there.

What should I install (or anything else) to install this package?

UPD: I found a solution - unpacked the package and executed setup.exe that was inside. But I'm pretty sure it's not an action supposed by vendor, so answers are still welcome.